# Why CiviCRM is not in wordpress.org/plugins/?

Tags: wordpress

Why CiviCRM is not in Plugins.wordpress.org? See https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=civicrm . There are 9 plugins, but not civicrm.

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM is not a conventional plugin like installing other wordpress plugins and requires a lot more work.  You can view installation instructions for wordpress platforms at https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installing+CiviCRM+for+WordPress